# Correct data loading, splitting and augmentation in Pytorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

The tutorial doesn't seem to explain how we should load, split and do proper augmentation.

Let's have a dataset consisting of cars and cats. The folder structure would be:

```
data
  cat
    0101.jpg
    0201.jpg
    ...
  dogs
    0101.jpg
    0201.jpg
    ...
```

At first, I loaded the dataset by datasets.ImageFolder function. Image Function has command "TRANSFORM" where we can set some augmentation commands, but we don't want to apply augmentation to test dataset! So let's stay with transform=None.

```
data = datasets.ImageFolder(root='data')
```

Apparently, we don't have folder structure train and test and therefore I assume a good approach would be to use [split_dataset function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.random_split)

```
    train_size = int(split * len(data))
    test_size = len(data) - train_size
    train_dataset, test_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(data, [train_size, test_size])
```

Now let's load the data the following way.

```
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset,
                                              batch_size=8,
                                              shuffle=True)
    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset,
                                              batch_size=8,
                                              shuffle=True)
```

How can I apply transformations (data augmentation) to the "train_loader" images?

Basically I need to: 1. load data from the folder structure explained above
2. split the data into test/train parts
3. apply augmentations on train part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a recommended way of doing this, but this is how I would workaround this problem:

Given that `torch.utils.data.random_split()` returns `Subset`, we cannot (<del>can we? not 100% sure here</del> I double-checked, we cannot) exploit their inner datasets, because they are the same (the only diference is in the indices). In this context, I would implement a simple class to apply transformations, something like this:

```py
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

class ApplyTransform(Dataset):
    """
    Apply transformations to a Dataset

    Arguments:
        dataset (Dataset): A Dataset that returns (sample, target)
        transform (callable, optional): A function/transform to be applied on the sample
        target_transform (callable, optional): A function/transform to be applied on the target

    """
    def __init__(self, dataset, transform=None, target_transform=None):
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.transform = transform
        self.target_transform = target_transform
        # yes, you don't need these 2 lines below :(
        if transform is None and target_transform is None:
            print("Am I a joke to you? :)")

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        sample, target = self.dataset[idx]
        if self.transform is not None:
            sample = self.transform(sample)
        if self.target_transform is not None:
            target = self.target_transform(target)
        return sample, target

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dataset)
```

And then use it before passing the dataset to the dataloader:

```py
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

train_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    # ...
])
train_dataset = ApplyTransform(train_dataset, transform=train_transform)

# continue with DataLoaders...
```

Comment: I will try it out. Another approach would be to use split-folders https://pypi.org/project/split-folders/ before the model.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can see this https://gist.github.com/kevinzakka/d33bf8d6c7f06a9d8c76d97a7879f5cb

```
def get_train_valid_loader(data_dir,
                           batch_size,
                           augment,
                           random_seed,
                           valid_size=0.1,
                           shuffle=True,
                           show_sample=False,
                           num_workers=4,
                           pin_memory=False):
    """
    Utility function for loading and returning train and valid
    multi-process iterators over the CIFAR-10 dataset. A sample
    9x9 grid of the images can be optionally displayed.
    If using CUDA, num_workers should be set to 1 and pin_memory to True.
    Params
    ------
    - data_dir: path directory to the dataset.
    - batch_size: how many samples per batch to load.
    - augment: whether to apply the data augmentation scheme
      mentioned in the paper. Only applied on the train split.
    - random_seed: fix seed for reproducibility.
    - valid_size: percentage split of the training set used for
      the validation set. Should be a float in the range [0, 1].
    - shuffle: whether to shuffle the train/validation indices.
    - show_sample: plot 9x9 sample grid of the dataset.
    - num_workers: number of subprocesses to use when loading the dataset.
    - pin_memory: whether to copy tensors into CUDA pinned memory. Set it to
      True if using GPU.
    Returns
    -------
    - train_loader: training set iterator.
    - valid_loader: validation set iterator.
    """
    error_msg = "[!] valid_size should be in the range [0, 1]."
    assert ((valid_size >= 0) and (valid_size <= 1)), error_msg

    normalize = transforms.Normalize(
        mean=[0.4914, 0.4822, 0.4465],
        std=[0.2023, 0.1994, 0.2010],
    )

    # define transforms
    valid_transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            normalize,
    ])
    if augment:
        train_transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.RandomCrop(32, padding=4),
            transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            normalize,
        ])
    else:
        train_transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            normalize,
        ])

    # load the dataset
    train_dataset = datasets.CIFAR10(
        root=data_dir, train=True,
        download=True, transform=train_transform,
    )

    valid_dataset = datasets.CIFAR10(
        root=data_dir, train=True,
        download=True, transform=valid_transform,
    )

    num_train = len(train_dataset)
    indices = list(range(num_train))
    split = int(np.floor(valid_size * num_train))

    if shuffle:
        np.random.seed(random_seed)
        np.random.shuffle(indices)

    train_idx, valid_idx = indices[split:], indices[:split]
    train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_idx)
    valid_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(valid_idx)

    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=train_sampler,
        num_workers=num_workers, pin_memory=pin_memory,
    )
    valid_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        valid_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=valid_sampler,
        num_workers=num_workers, pin_memory=pin_memory,
    )

    # visualize some images
    if show_sample:
        sample_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
            train_dataset, batch_size=9, shuffle=shuffle,
            num_workers=num_workers, pin_memory=pin_memory,
        )
        data_iter = iter(sample_loader)
        images, labels = data_iter.next()
        X = images.numpy().transpose([0, 2, 3, 1])
        plot_images(X, labels)

    return (train_loader, valid_loader)
```

Seems that he use `sampler=train_sampler` to do the split.